# converting a design to css

Tags: css

I have a designer that has been helping me with a website. Unfortunately, they are unavailable at this time and I need to get this project done. Unfortunately, my CSS is not making the result look like the design.  I have the following HTML

```
<h1>CUSTOMERS WELCOME</h1>
```

My CSS for H1 tags is as follows:

```
  h1 { color:#2D2D2D; font-weight:normal; font-family:Arial; font-size:24pt; letter-spacing:75%; line-height:24px; }
```

The designer wrote me a note before they left saying H1 tags should use the following settings: *Font - Arial, Regular, 24 pt, color - HEX: #2D2D2D, Tracking (letter spacing) 75, Leading (line spacing) 24 Text is full justified*

What am I doing wrong? My H1 tags look larger and bolder than those in the design.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Each browser will render differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
font-size:24pt;
```

change `pt` to `px`

`pt` stands for points (I think) and `px` for pixels. That should work better because a pixel is a pixel, `pt` or `em` can vary from browser to browser

Answer (score 0):

Point sizes vary from browser to browser and from OS to OS. It sounds like your designer is not that familiar with web design, where we generally use pixel measurements to maintain consistency.

24 points != 24 pixels, you can't just change units and expect it to be the same. In my screenshot (FF Win7) of 24pt text, the font is actually 21 pixels high.

[image]

See this chart: http://sureshjain.wordpress.com/2007/07/06/53/

Answer (score 0):

For the `font-size`, I would use 24px instead of 24pt. Points are used more for print than screens.